# SQL Server performance Issue with simple SELECT query

Tags: sql-server, database-performance

I have a quick question, and I hope you guys can help me.

I have a table which contains 4 columns and 1 million rows of data. There is a clustered index on the `ID` [`Int, Unique, Not Null`] column and a non-clustered index on the `CreateDate` [`Date, Not Null`] column.

However, when I fire up

```
SELECT *
FROM [DatabaseName].[dbo].[TableName]
```

It takes more than 10 seconds to return the whole table.

Does this mean that I really need to update my server machine? Or there are more things I could do for improving the performance?

Thank you a lot for helping me.

Best.

Comment: What are the other columns? Are the indexes in ram? What’s the data size? What is the query waiting on when you run it?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention there was NO(LOCK) as well. It wasn't waiting on anything, The size for the other two columns are nvarchar(50) NULL. The Indexes are in ram. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Why return 1 million row of data at one time?

Comment: Are you running the query over a network? The schema you’ve suggested would mean about 100mb of data; 10mb/s isn’t an unreasonably low network throughout to be the cause of the “poor performance”. This would show in `dm_exec_sessions` as an ASYNC_NETWORK_IO wait.

Comment: Well... you are trying to return 1 million rows of data... and all columns.  so, your indexes don't matter here since you don't have a where clause, order by, or explicit list of columns to return. 10 seconds isn't a terribly long time, especially if the db can't fit into RAM. You've given nothing about the hardware, other sessions, wait stats, etc. I would not be overly worried. You can improve performance by not returning 1 million rows, or columns which you don't need.

Comment: Yes, 1 million rows at one time. Client wanted to show the data over past 13 month at once in another view built upon this one. They didn't provide any hardware information over their server what so ever. However, I know their network speed is over 100 mb/sec. Their bandwidth is even higher. The reason why 10 sec concerns me is this query is slowing the view by 10 sec (total of 11 sec), and the view will be imported into Power BI Report Server on premise via Direct Query. After the whole process, the loading time in Power BI became too much.

Comment: I realized for some reason, if the query is running 1 sec faster, Power BI will render the visual at least 3 sec faster. And the client won't pass QA until this is fixed in QA. I was suspecting the QA Server does not have enough computing power, but the client insisted unless this thing runs smooth in QA, or it would never make to Production.

Comment: You just said *another view built upon this one*. This changes things too... depending on what you mean with the word *view*. You shouldn't `select *` from a view either... what happens when the definition of the view changes? Also, since you have an index on the view it seems, it's materialized which changes things. 1 second is negligible.